# Error while creating OS X Mavericks bootable USB

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bootable-disk

I am running on `OS X Mavericks GM` and now that `Mavericks` has finally released, I downloaded it from App Store. I wanted to make a bootable USB of it so I followed [This Tutorial](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-make-os-x-mavericks-bootable-usb-flash-drive-for-a-clean-install/) but when I tried to run the command for copying the files from `.app` to `USB` I got the following error

```
Ankurs-MacBook-Pro:~ Ankur$ sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia
--volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app -nointeraction
Password:
sudo: /Applications/Install OS X Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia: command not found
Ankurs-MacBook-Pro:~ Ankur$
```

What can I do to resolve this issue?

**EDIT**
Using [DiskMaker X](http://diskmakerx.com) I got the same error

[image]

Comment: well, did you assured that the file is existent? If you open the finder you can open the package with a right click and then "show folder contents"

Comment: I already checked it, it's there. I can see `createinstallmedia`

Comment: Not sure if this will fix your problem, but you also have the wrong syntax. At the end of your command, it must be a double dash, so `--nointeraction`

Comment: tried it, didn't help, tho I am able to make bootable disk of `Mountain Lion` with `DiskMaker X`

Comment: I would recommend re-downloading the Mountain Lion installer just to make sure your copy isn't somehow corrupted.  I used the same command you have and it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Had the same problem. Thought the file "createinstallmedia" was missing, but that wasn't the case.
Then I realised I simply needed to make it executable with the following command:

```
sudo chmod +x /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia
```

This will create the executable that DiskMaker X initially couldn't find. 
After running the command above you shouldn't have the error anymore.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I didn't immediately notice that `createinstallmedia` is an executable within the newly-downloaded `Install Mavericks.app`, as opposed to somewhere already in the system path.

Comment: In my case the `Install macOS *.app` simply did NOT have `Resources` folder, so maybe [see how use Disk Utility to make bootable from `InstallESD.dmg`](https://superuser.com/a/444086/896280) (if you have the same issue, and your `Install macOS *.app` directory contains `InstallESD.dmg` file).

Answer (score 2):

**Solved it**

I copied the same `Install OS X Mavericks.app` in a different Mac that was running on `Mountain Lion 10.8.5` and tried [DiskMaker X](http://diskmakerx.com/) and it worked. I'm not sure but maybe the reason was that `OS X Mavericks GM Build` doesn't support the command that was used or maybe there's a different way to copy things on `OS X Mavericks` using terminal.

**Update**

I tried making another bootable USB using my Mac (OS X 10.8.5) with the same `Install OS X Mavericks.app` but failed to do so, it seems that you can only make a bootable USB on the same system that you've downloaded `Mavericks` on.
[image]

Comment: Interesting. I got a different error from 10.6 ( http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106172/create-bootable-drive-from-command-line )